# rails storing rendered view in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
- upcoming = ""
- past = ""
- @saves.each do |save|
  - if save.con1
    - upcoming += render "save_individual"
  - else if save.con2
    - past += render "save_individual"

  - if params[:show_saved]
    .tab-content
      #upcoming.tab-pane.fade.in.active
        = upcoming
      #past.tab-pane.fade
        = past
  - else
    = render "save_individual"
```

I am trying to reuse an existing view for two pages, one will show content without tabs and other with past/upcoming tabs with respective filtered content, Is what I am trying is correct, I see plain html output rendered though, is there any legitimate ways to do that?

Comment: The layout of this looks like it might be incorrect. Do you want to create a tab for each save, or a single tab at the end including all saves?

Comment: yes you are right, corrected it, thanks and applied @Simple Lime's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing seems to work, you just need to make those strings [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) (you could also use [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) or [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)).

```
= upcoming.html_safe
```

and

```
= past.html_safe
```

should fix it. Do note, this opens you up to malicious user input, that `sanitize` helper is your friend if that's a possibility.

A simpler way to accomplish what you're doing might be to do something like:

```
- if params[:show_saved]
  .tab-content
    #upcoming.tab-pane.fade.in.active
      - @saves.select(&:con1).each do |save|
        = render 'save_individual'
    #past.tab-pane.fade
      - @saves.select { |save| save.con2 && !save.con1 }.each do |save|
        = render 'save_individual'
- else
  = render 'save_individual'
```

that's untested, but shows the general idea, I think.

Comment: As @michael points out, the indentation seems off in your example, my example is assuming the `- if params[:show_saved]` is supposed to be in line with the `- @users.each do |save|` line

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried render_to_string?